# go.scatterpolar : trying to render radar graph with various lines color not working

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to build a radar chart where each line is of different color.

I feel like I have followed the doc closely and I am now facing an error I can't seem solve, especially because NO ERROR is output!

here is some dummy data I am working with :

```
r = [52,36,85]
theta = ["analytique", "analogique", "affectif"]

colors = ["blue", "red","yellow"]
```

Here is what I have for my graph:

```
for i in range(len(theta)):
    fig_reception.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
        mode='lines+text',
        theta=[theta[i]],
        r=[r[i]],
     ,   line_color=text_colors[i],
        fillcolor='#d3d3d3',
        marker=dict(color=text_colors),
    ))


fig_reception.update_layout(autosize=False,
                            height=305,
                  polar=dict(radialaxis = dict(range=[0,100],visible = False),
                                          angularaxis=dict(rotation=180,direction="clockwise") )
                            )
fig_reception.update_layout(
    template=None,
    polar = dict(bgcolor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)"),)

fig_reception.update_layout(
    font=dict(
        size=16,
        color="black",
        family="Courier New, monospace",

    ),
    title="Réception",
    title_font_family="Courier New, monospace",
    showlegend=False
)
```

what's strange its that when I hover each line, a frame with the right color and value shows up.

Here is a picture
[image]

Comment: I don't follow completely: your data has only 1 trace, so that will only have 1 color. If you want multiple colors, you will need [multiple traces](https://plotly.com/python/radar-chart/#multiple-trace-radar-chart). Could you perhaps clarify how the radar/spyder plot should look in the end?

Comment: I guess I may be misunderstanding but to me I am creating a trace for each value inside of the theta list, which is 4 traces. Yes, let me clarify, at the end, it needs to show a traditional radar chart with 3 lines (the fourth is there to complete the triangle but its just a repeat). SO basically a triangle where each segment has a different color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a full solution for you, but I hope my answer leads you in the right way.

#### Simple start

First, let's simplify and plot a radar/spyder plot with default colors:

```py
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

r = [52,36,85]
theta = ["analytique", "analogique", "affectif"]
types = ["one", "two","three"]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(r=r, theta=theta, type=types))
df
```

|  | r | theta | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 52 | analytique | one |
| 1 | 36 | analogique | two |
| 2 | 85 | affectif | three |

Plotting this with [`plotly.express.line_polar`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line_polar), gives:

```py
fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True, markers=True)
fig.show()
```

[image: Radar plot with three categories]

#### Every edge its own color

Now, you want every edge to have it's own color. For the sake of this example, I assume you want this color to be based on the column `type` which I defined earlier.

Simply plotting this straight away will not work, it will only give you the dots, no lines:

```py
fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True, color='type', markers=True)
fig.show()
```

[image: broken radar plot without lines, only dots]

You need to duplicate the rows, and assign sequential data points the same `type`.

```py
# First append the df to itself, but only keep the r and theta columns
# This will make the type column NaN for the appended rows
df2 = pd.concat([df, df[['r', 'theta']]]).sort_values(by=['r', 'theta'])
# Now fill the NaN type value by taking the type value of the next row
df2.type.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)
# The last type value should be equal to the first type value to close the loop
# This needs to be set manually
df2.type.fillna(df2.type.iloc[0], inplace=True)
df2
```

|  | r | theta | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 36 | analogique | two |
| 1 | 36 | analogique | one |
| 0 | 52 | analytique | one |
| 0 | 52 | analytique | three |
| 2 | 85 | affectif | three |
| 2 | 85 | affectif | two |

Now if you plot that, you will get a triangle with every edge having a separate color:

```py
fig = px.line_polar(df2, r='r', theta='theta', color='type', line_close=True, markers=True)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Not sure why the categories have changed order, but you can probably fix that by sorting the `df2` DataFrame differently.

#### Text labels

If you would like to have text labels in your graph, you'll [find in the docs](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.line_polar) that there is a `text` parameter:

```py
fig = px.line_polar(df2, r='r', theta='theta', color='type', text='r', line_close=True, markers=True)
fig.update_traces(textposition='top center')
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, I see your solution, it is clever, let me try it out to see!

Comment: hat's down sir, now my job to get it working with go.scatterpolar

Comment: The plotly express library uses go.scatterpolar under the hood, you can access the objects through fig.data or something like that. But what do you need go.scatterpolar for? Why does the px library not suffice?

Comment: I may be wrong but I think that px.line_polar does not allow to write the "r" value on the graph, like there is no mode parameter

Comment: @Murcielago, updated my answer. Check the docs for plotly express to see what else it can do.

Comment: no way lol! I spent quite a bit of time trying to do that, well actually I am trying to get that value outside of the circle, I thought go scatterpolar could have been the way to go, but haven't found out yet, it may not be even possible. tbh, the doc shows examples about  both px.line_polar and go.scatterpolar, but does not explain when to choose what, do you have an advice on that?

Comment: I always choose the `px` as it can do 90% of the things I need. Only when it needs very specific adjustments of the graph I fall back on `go`. But even in those cases I first create the basic graph using the `px` library and then edit the `go` objects by iterating over the `fig.data` object. It contains a tuple of `go` objects. There are also [functions that can iterate over the traces](https://plotly.com/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#conditionally-updating-traces).

Comment: that's a good point, I'll keep the advice in mind!